# Rails: Validates greater_than_or_equal_to 0 does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I shouldn't be able to set `user.fee_email = -1` but I can, even though I've specified in my model that the `numericality` of `fee_email` should be positive.

Given:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :fee_email, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
...
end
```

This should not happen:

```
2.2.1 :002 > a = User.first
2.2.1 :003 > a.fee_email
 => #<BigDecimal:43cbbe0,'0.0',9(27)> 
2.2.1 :004 > a.fee_email = -1
 => -1 
2.2.1 :005 > a.fee_email
 => #<BigDecimal:43b5688,'-0.1E1',9(27)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't invoke a validation, call `a.valid?` or `a.invalid?` or `a.save` to invoke validation and check the error message with `a.errors`.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving it. `a.save`. It wont work.

Validation work when you try saving it in the database. You can assign anything to the retreived record(this is a copy),it wont make any difference. Once you try to save, the validation can fail and the changes will not be saved.